# Show that $|\lambda_i(A)|<1$ iff $|\lambda_i(\beta A)|<1$ $\forall \beta: |\beta|\leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here $\lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue of the square matrix $A$. I would like to know if these two inequalities are equivalent.  I assumed they are (please correct me if I am wrong). So I tried to proof the equivalence, please check  if it's right and formal:

Proof:

We know that for any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ it's a fact that $\lambda_i(\beta A)=\beta \lambda_i(A)$, so

$|\lambda_i(\beta A)|<1$ $\iff$ $|\beta \lambda_i(A)|<1$ $\iff$ $|\beta| |\lambda_i(A)|<1$

Since $|\beta|\leq 1$, $|\beta| |\lambda_i(A)|<1$ $\iff$ $|\lambda_i(A)|<1$

Comment: I think that last equivalence it's right, but I'm afraid that I went "too fast" in this and a few more steps would be "ideal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last equivalence if you wish:

"$\Rightarrow$" Take $\beta=1$.

"$\Leftarrow$" Multiply the inequality by $|\beta|$.

P.S. To me if something "went too fast" in this proof it were the very first fact: why $\lambda_i(\beta A)=\beta \lambda_i(A)$? It is the only nontrivial passage.

Comment: showing this fact it's not a part of the proof, I just used it. The problem is I am not 100% this fact it's actually right though

Comment: @gustavoreche It is true. Take e.g. the Jordan form decomposition $A=SJS^{-1}$. Then $\beta A=S(\beta J)S^{-1}$, and the eigenvalues of  $\beta A$ are those of $\beta J$, the diagonal elements, which are $\beta\lambda_i(A)$.

Comment: Ok, so it's okay to use this fact and not proving it right? If this so, the proof its right?

Comment: @gustavoreche I would not accept it on my exam from students without a proof or a reference. Otherwise the rest is ok.